# Submit formulario sin salir de la página

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo un formulario en HTML, donde únicamente tengo que activar una función en otro archivo.

Ejemplo:

```
<form action="formula.html">
  <input type="submit">Enviar</submit>
</form>
```

Abajo del formulario tengo más contenido de la página.

Necesito que al presionar sobre submit, se ejecute lo que hay en formula.html, pero sin salir de la página principal.

¿Es posible? ¿Cómo se haría?

Comment: Si es posible, para ello debes crear una `div` no visible (u oculta) y colocar el `target` del `form` a que se dirija hacia el `id` de la división.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si es posible, para ello debes crear un `iframe` no visible (u oculto) y colocar el `target` del `form` a que se dirija hacia el `id` del `iframe`.

```html
<form action="formula.html" target="request">
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
<iframe id="request"></iframe>
<div id="response"></div>
```

Código de ejemplo para: **formulario.html**

```js
 var html=window.opener.getElementById("response").innerHTML,
  html="el envió del formulario finalizo con exito!"
```

Espero esto ayude a aclara un poco el posible código que como respuesta podria hacer el servidor ante la solicitud al pulsar el boton `"Enviar"`

Es importante aclarar que esta solución existe desde que se invento la web (hace mas de 20 años), sin embargo actualmente se utilizan técnicas modernas tales como [AJAX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX).

Comment: cómo exactamente estás ejecutando la función del otro archivo?

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo dentro del `iframe` se cargara la pagina como repuesta del formulario enviado, dependerá de dicha pagina el código que coloque @Pepemujica (desplegar, imprimir, formular), la acción a realizar, voy a modificar la respuesta para intentar aclarar un poco la posible acción a realizar.

Comment: Hola @fwBasic !, estoy intentando, pero no resulta. La página realmente no tiene funciones, únicamente recibe parámetros de la url (ocalhost/control?action=NOTIFICACION&notificacion=PERFIL_AC‌​TIVO&payload=%22Otro‌​_Perfil%22 ) para realizar ciertas acciones, en este caso, cambiar de perfil. Pero no logro que haga nada

Comment: @Pepemujica te recomiendo que recrees en tu servidor el ejemplo que te deje aqui, por lo que veo estas trabajando en localhost.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar ajax para hacer la petición sin tener que refrescar la página.

Aqui te anexo un ejemplo, espero que te sirva

```
   <form id="id_form" action="formula.html">
         <input type="submit">Enviar</submit>
   </form>


$("#id_form").on("submit", function(e){
   //Code: Action (like ajax...)
   e.preventDefault();

   $.ajax({
            url         : 'formula.html',
            type        : 'POST',
            data        : {val:inputs}, //Aquí tienes que enviar la información que necesita formula.html si no tiene nada puedes dejarlo así {}
            cache       : false,
            async       : false,
            dataType    : 'json',
            contentType : "application/json",
            success: function(response)
            {
               alert('datos guardados')
            },
            error : function(response)
            {
                alert('error al guardar los datos')
            }
   //return false;
 })
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la respuesta. No me está funcionando, mi url es: (localhost/control?action=NOTIFICACION&notificacion=PERFIL_AC‌​TIVO&payload=%22Otro‌​_Perfil%22) Lo que necesito es que se ejecute la url, pero que la página se mantenga donde está, es decir (localhost/control.hmtl)

Comment: ¿Quizás no funcione porque Jorge pone id_form y @Pepemujica no tiene?. Prueba a cambiar esto: $("#id_form") por esto: $("form") y quizás te funcione o agrégale un id a tu form.

Comment: Si, tienes que poner un id a tu form o poner directamente el seleccionador form, la idea del iframe se me hace bastante mala ya que cargas una página completa dentro de una etiqueta eso puede hacer que tu página sea lenta.

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que necesitas llamar una función de javascript presente en otro archivo, puedes hacerlo con jquery de la siguiente forma:

**archivo1.html**: Desde este archivo vamos a invocar la función que está en arhcivo2.js

En el head incluye lo siguiente:

```
<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Archivo en donde está la función que vamos a invocar-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="archivo2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).on("click","#invocar", Invocar);
    function Invocar(){
        Invocando();          //aquí estamos activando la función del otro archivo
    }
</script>
```

En el body solo necesitas lo siguiente:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" id="invocar"></submit>
</form>
```

.

**archivo2.js**: Aquí está la función de js que invocaremos (ojo que es un archivo .js, no .html)

```
function Invocando(){
    alert("Quién osa invocarme?");
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado, para cualquier duda solo deja un comentario.

Comment: Estimado **@Roberto** lo que se quiere mas que ejecutar una acción en otro archivo es: _enviar un formulario al servidor_ pero como todos sabemos esta acción _desplegara una pagina como respuesta al envió del formulario_ y es principalmente eso lo que no se quiere, en el ejemplo que coloque explico con detalles como hacerlo.

Comment: @fwBasic hola!! en realidad lo que necesito es enviar parametros por url. Esto activa ciertas funciones, pero necesito que no se vaya de la pagina donde se encuentra

Comment: @fwBasic Es básicamente un control remoto, que hace ciertas tareas. El menú principal se accede así: localhost/control.html. Ahí muestra ciertas opciones básicas, pero ingresando a localhost/control?action=NOTIFICACION&notificacion=PERFIL_ACTIVO&payload=%22Otro_Perfil%22 ingresa a otro perfil, donde se muestran otras cosas, pero la pantalla del control queda en blanco, por lo que necesito enviar esa url, pero permanecer en la página principal para tener el resto de las opciones disponibles

Comment: Pepe, Puedes enviar esos parámetros por la función que puse en mi respuesta.

- Al invocar: Invocando("Gimán? ","León-O? ","Gokú?")

- Al recibir la invocación: function Invocando(param1, param2, param3)

Respecto a lo que dice @fwBasic, tal vez tiene razón y no he entendido en absoluto lo que buscas, si aún no encuentras la respuesta, siéntete libre de modificar tu pregunta.